# typo3 controller error when no parameters, how to set defaults

Tags: parameters, typo3, default, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a form that is accessed in various ways, sometimes there are 2 variables transported ... with every template I define the variables but with a direct link I get an error, probably because `$newTicket` is not defined ...

how can I give default values ? does that resolve the error ??

```
/**
 * action form
 * 
 * @param array $newTicket
 * @return void
 */
public function formAction($newTicket = array('origin' => '', 'destination' => '')) {
    $this->view->assign('ticket', $newTicket);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to make an param needed you only must set its default value.

```
/**
 * action form
 * 
 * @param array $newTicket
 * @return void
 */
public function formAction($newTicket = array()) {
    $this->view->assign('ticket', $newTicket);
}
```

after changing, clear all your typo3 cache in the install tool.